# Can Windows 7 x64 be installed in UEFI on GPT disk on Mac Mini Late 2014?

Tags: uefi

Wondering if there is any special way i can get a 
UEFI installation of Windows 7 x64 on my Mac Mini.

I have read about UEFI Duet, though would this work on a Mac?

Thanks.

Comment: There a reason you don't want to use Bootcamp?

Comment: [This extraordinarily long thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/win7-x64-booting-natively-via-efi-no-bios-emulation.696523/) on MacRumors covers this topic. I stopped following it long ago, but the last I checked, it appeared that it was possible to do on a few specific Mac models, but it would fail on most, and be very difficult even on the few on which it would work. Overall, it's likely to be easier to install in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode using Boot Camp. Windows 8 and 10 are more likely to be installable in EFI mode.

Comment: When i attempt to boot UEFI duet both on ssd and usb, it says _boot error, with and without refind. Attempting to boot from "efi" on bootable windows 7 USB with and without refind just starts with blank black screen. I am not even sure that late 2014 mac mini has EFI 2.0 on it, am i wrong? This is what i think Windows 7 EFI boot needs.